# why Android Mobile phone drive folder is not visible in my computer?

Tags: internal-storage, internal-sd, remote-access

when i connect my infocus mobile with my desktop through data cable. only Driver Setup file opened. Internal memory drive not visible in the desktop. but till yesterday its working properly. today i have deleted 2 files, after that it's not working and I don't remember what file i have deleted. I tried to repair Phone Driver software but it ask's me to insert disk.  i don't know what disk it asked to insert. kindly give me the solution as soon as possible because i kept all of my official files in my phone.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for that USB driver:
http://freeandroidroot.com/download-infocus-usb-drivers/
http://flashtool.org/2/download-infocus-usb-driver.html

Answer (score 0):

There are too many possibilities and I faced few of them so I'm suggesting here not answering directly. From your description the files you deleted probably the problem but I don't know where did you delete them from !. So, tracing the issue this problem could be simply an issue at the driver and one of the fixes regarding that is to plugin your phone, check the drivers manager (assuming you are on Windows) for the ADB driver or interface (You can use [USBDeview](http://www.topnotchtablets.com/FixUSBproblems) instead of the devices manager if it doesn't show there). Uninstall it then plug off your phone and restart your PC and connect now.

Another solution is simply doing same steps but after the restarting step, install your phone usb driver. Search for this one since I have no info about infocus usb drivers. Then plugin your phone.

Another one is to use debug mode. sometimes this method does work. To activate debug mode, go to Settings > Developer options > and check USB debugging.  Plug in your device. Go to Settings > Developer options. When a warning about this mode for developers..etc, Click OK.

Las suggestion I can remember is to change the cable and/or try plugging on another computer just to make sure it is NOT the cable.